# Use store blob image in database as a url in html

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, apex-code

I'm storing images to a blob column in a Database table.
Then through a package i'm using htp.p to render some html elements and I also want to display the stored image in the  tag.

I created an Application item "IMAGE_F" & Application process "IMAGE_PROCESS"

```
 begin

for c1 in ( select *

              from QUESTIONS_T

             where ID =:IMAGE_F

) loop

    --

    sys.htp.init;

    sys.owa_util.mime_header(

        'image/png',

        false

    );

    sys.htp.p('Content-length: '

                || sys.dbms_lob.getlength(c1.FILE_BLOB) );

    sys.htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'

                || c1.FILENAME

                || '"');

    sys.htp.p('Cache-Control: max-age=3600');  -- tell the browser to cache for one hour, adjust as necessary

    sys.owa_util.http_header_close;

    sys.wpg_docload.download_file(c1.FILE_BLOB);

    apex_application.stop_apex_engine;

end loop;

end;
```

then I'm using the img tag as the following:

```
            <img src="'

            || 'f?p='

            ||:app_id

            || ':10:'

            ||:app_session

            || ':APPLICATION_PROCESS=IMAGE_PROCESS:'

            ||:debug

            || '::IMAGE_F:'

            || IMAGE_ID

            || '">'
```

but it's not working and image is not showing.
I'm using ORACLE APEX version 21.2 , Oracle Database 19c.

Comment: Try ontent-Disposition: inline  (and I assume page 10 is an empty page?)

Comment: Page 10 is only having a dynamic content region type.
How can I use the ontent-Disposition, is it Javascript ?

Comment: No - check your own code that you already posted.  That's where content disposition is.